# Is $g \circ f$ invertible if both $f$ and $g$ are invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

Is $g \circ f$ invertible if both $f$ and $g$ are invertible?.

I know that $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$.

This is what I have so far:

If $f$ is invertible, $f^{-1} : B \rightarrow A$, $f^{-1} \circ f = id_A$. And if $g$ is invertible,  $g^{-1} : C \rightarrow B$, $g^{-1} \circ g = id_B$.

Given all of this information, however, I am not sure how this proves that $g \circ f$ is invertible.

Comment: What do you think its inverse would be? Check that it is.

Comment: Maybe you would like a more "practical" formulation of same question. Suppose you know $y$, you know that $y=g(f(x))$, and you know that you can invert $g$ and $f$. What is $x$? 

An even more practical example: suppose $24 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot x$. What is $x$? How did you get it?

Comment: @amd That is the converse of the given statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the fact that co.position of functions is associative, and then $(g \circ f)^{-1}= f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ . We can check this as follows:

$(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}) \circ (g\circ f)=
f^{-1} \circ (g^{-1} \circ g)\circ f= (f^{-1})\circ id \circ (f)= f^{-1} \circ f= id$

Comment: You have done only half the job (however of course swapping the roles of $f$ and $g$ does the other half).